# Why am I only able to scrape 100 tweets with snscrape?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

So granted I'm not technical or experience with Python, but I need to scrape maybe 5,000 tweets from the Twitter account of a particular user. I got it working, but I can only scrape 100 tweets — I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code I use:

```
snscrape --jsonl --progress --max-results 100 twitter-search "from:jack" > user-tweets.json

tweets_df = pd.read_json('user-tweets.json', lines=True)

tweets_df
```

And then it throws a message saying there's invalid syntax at the "100" line, but it still returns 100 tweets anyway. If I try and increase that number to, say, 1000 tweets, it just doesn't work at all. How do I need to fix this so I can retrieve more tweets?

Comment: Have you read their documentation?  Twitter limits the number of tweets you can fetch per hour, per day, and per month.  Twitter has an official API that doesn't rely on hacky web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

I can get 5000 tweets in windows 11 with `Python` v 3.10.8 and `snscrape` v 0.5.0.20230113.

I think you are using lower version of Python or snscrape.

From the [snscrape](https://pypi.org/project/snscrape/) documentation, it required Python v 3.8 or later.

Can you check your Python version?
`python --version` in your terminal.

[image]

And check `snscrape` version?

```
snscrape                  0.5.0.20230113
```

You can check by this commend

```
pip list
```

[image]
[image]

This is I got 5000 tweets result.
by this commend.

```
snscrape --jsonl --progress --max-results 5000 twitter-search "from:jack" > user-tweets.json
```

and Code

```
import pandas as pd

tweets_df = pd.read_json('user-tweets.json', lines=True)

print(tweets_df)
```

[image]

[image]